# Blender does not import correct color from images

Tags: vertex-colors, image-sequence

[image: Blender file view]

[image: Original photo]

Im trying to make a product design in 3D for a friend but the colors just wont match the original image. Its exported from cymk illustrator. How to fix please

Comment: Hello could you please share one of your images? Use a platform like workupload

Comment: If you export you should always export to RGB and NOT CMYK. Give that a try.

Comment: The reason you should export to RGB is that Blender is RGB-based, very simple. CMYK will result in what you posted.